# Consume a Web service thought an Active Directory

Tags: python, web-services, ldap

I have a project in which I have to consume a web service authenticating against Active Directory. I have my system written in python3, python-ldap module is not ported yet, so I want to know a way to acheive this `consumption`.

In the worst case, I will create a standalone consumer in python2.5, but I want to know how to consume a web service logged in an active directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it with python-ntlm a project in google that handles ntlm for www-authentication: negotiate, http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/ thanks!